# Can I copy all tables from a URL?

Tags: http, automation, ms-word

My task is to copy tables from a public domain and format it later in Word. I have created a software where I just have to enter two values and the table is displayed to me on a web page. Then I have to copy this table into Word.
I was wondering if there was an easier way to achieve this....
I would even like to know if it is possible to store all the values I type to a TXT file or Excel sheet and programmatically copy the displayed web pages to Word.

Please help me and don't down-vote.....

Okay here are the detailed steps:

1. Open a webpage
2. Fill in a form with  4 fields
3. A new webpage opens based on what input you provide
4. Copy 2 tables from that webpage
5. Paste the 2 tables in MS Word 2007
6. Open browser again and go back to previous page
7. Enter new values in the webpage
8. Repeat all the steps

P.S There are more than 700 tables to be copied each week

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you need...anyway...
If you download the page (programmatically of course) you can parse it as XML (I assume it's a well-formed XML file otherwise you may have to use some *dirty* trick to find all tables). Then you can put all data on Word (by automation, you can even do all these stuffs from a Word macro, just download the HTML file, "parse" it to find tables and paste that text as HTML).
I would provide some example but it can't really be language-agnostic.

Comment: Your idea would work for another use case maybe. But I need to give two values as input and only then it moves on to the page I need. So if I need 600 tables , I need to give 1200 values as input.

Comment: Wow, maybe not so easy...
But you may send keystrokes to the page then do the parsing

Comment: No more answers ? So I guess there is no faster way  :(

Comment: Hmmmm can you explain better what you have to do? Kind of step by step instructions to complete the task?

Comment: There is a faster way, do not worry! :) Write a small application (C#, for example). Put in a form a WebControl, you will use that to view the site instead of the _standard_ web browser. Once it loaded the page (check their events) you inject (using the ScriptManager) in the page the javascript code to fill the form and force a submit.  Then, accessing the Page property you get the tables you need. Then you may simply copy & paste HTML text to clipboard or use Word automation to paste the HTML text you grabbed.

Comment: I guess you'll need a little bit of time and try & fail to get the right result but it can be done. Handmade tests for web pages are made more or less in this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I'll try out what you suggested and get back to you as soon as possible  :)